# Can i force to show days in AnyGantt timeline header?

Tags: gantt-chart, anychart

My gantt chart has activities planned for two years. The problem is that when the chart is plotted, the timeline header shows only months and years. Is it possible to force to show days? I'm using zoom to see only the current month, and that would be easier to see start and end dates.

[Example of my gantt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ksIeo.png)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to apply the minimum() and maximum() methods to a scale:

```
var scale = chart.xScale();
scale.minimum(Date.UTC(2000, 1, 23));
scale.maximum(Date.UTC(2000, 2, 1));
```

https://api.anychart.com/7.14.3/anychart.scales.GanttDateTime#minimum
https://api.anychart.com/7.14.3/anychart.scales.GanttDateTime#maximum

Like is shown here: https://jsfiddle.net/9re7Lswc/